# Resize navbar logo on scroll down, Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't manage to resize the size of the navbar logo using javascript.

I'm new to Javascript.

Thank you all.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var logo = document.getElementsByClassName("logo");
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('white');
    logo.style.width = '30px';
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('white');
    logo.style.width = '60px';
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <img src="assets/images/Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: For starters, you'll want to correct your HTML. Put the javascript in a `<script>` tag, and count your `<div>`s -- there seems to be one extra. After that, what would be really helpful is a working demo showcasing your issue. Try the in-built code preview, or Codepen/Jsfiddle and provide the link.

Comment: @Guy555 please add your css for the classes you are trying to add, and it would help if you could specify the height of the logo also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the bat I see that you're using `getElementsByClassName` method which returns an array. If you are using JQuery, and it looks like you are, I recommend saying `logo = $('.logo');` or changing it to an id and using `getElementById`.

Comment: Thanks alot! I changed the getElementsByClassName to getElementById and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need jquery

```
<script>
    let logo = document.querySelector('#logo')
    let nav = document.querySelector('#nav')
    if(window.scrollTop > 0){
    nav.classList.add('white')
    nav.style.width= "30px"
    }else{
    nav.classList.add('white')
    nav.style.width= "30px"
    }
</script>
```

and add id to your img tag

```
<img id="logo" class="logo" src="..some.jpg" alt="some image">
```